# Would this cause a memory leak

Tags: c++

I have a code that is essentially a data accumulator and when I run it on my server it uses pretty much 100% of the ram, its more like 93% but i suspect there is something that stops me from reaching 100%. This is bad and I have been actively trying to figure out if I have a potential memory leak. Here is one of my thoughts and maybe someone can tell me if this may be the cause. Here is a simplified version of what is going on.

In my code I have two classes A and B. Class B contains some information and class A accumulates B classes and contains managing functions. One of the members of A is a vector of Bs.

The information I put in B comes from a program. This program gives me a reference to a class C that has has way too much information and I only need part of it, hence I created B.

Once the vector of Bs is sufficiently large I save the information to a file, clear the vector and continue accumulating Bs.

What happens when you instantly dereference newly allocated memory? The situation would look something like the following:

```
    std::vector<B> Baccumulator;

    Baccumulator.push_back( *(new B(C)) );
```

Let us assume we push back 1 000 000 times just for an arbitrary number before saving and clearing. From my plebeian knowledge, I ask for memory with "new", construct my class B by giving it the correct arguments and then pushing back B creates a copy of the newly created B in the vector.

How do I free the memory I asked for with "new" since copies are put in the vector?

Comment: `Baccumulator.push_back(B(C));`

Comment: `*new` is almost automatically a leak. In theory you could keep a reference to it and then delete on the reference's address but at that point you are just trying to come up with an excuse to make `*new` work. I guess there's also `&*new` but again, there's no real reason to choose to do that.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux or you're using Qt and your `new`ed widgets are immediately parented with their parameter. But definitely not common usage.

Comment: *"How do I free the memory I asked for with "new" since copies are put in the vector?"* - You can't. You have a leak.

Comment: @Quentin I'll admit I haven't though of the case of objects that register themselves.

Comment: I understand now, I'll change the the way I did things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it would leak but the good news is you don't have to do that. You can simply say

```
Baccumulator.push_back(B(C));
```

or

```
Baccumulator.emplace_back(C);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a rule of thumb: any object created with `new` requires a `delete` at some point. You use a `new`, pass the resulting (and dereferenced) object by value and - as you will loose track of the original object - will have no chance to `delete` it later ->> memory leak.

To avoid this, you could write...

```
Baccumulator.push_back(B(C));

Baccumulator.emplace_back(C);

B *b = new B(C);
Baccumulator.push_back(*b);
// do something else with 'b'
delete b;
```